# Can't send data to Google Cloud Messaging when I try to send data

Tags: android, service, background, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send data to GCM when a location is changed. 
The following things works:

- My program notice when location is changed or when the timer is over.
- I can register my device to GCM
- I can send data to GCM when I hit a buttom. I use this code:

  ```
   public void sendMessageToGCMAppServer(final String status) {
          new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

              protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                  String msg = "";
                  try {
                      Bundle data = new Bundle();

                  Clock clock = new Clock();
                  String timestamp = clock.getTimeStamp();

                  data.putString("my_message", status + " - " + timestamp);
                  data.putString("my_action",
                          "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
                  String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
                  gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                  msg = "Data sended to GCM";

              } catch (IOException ex) {
                  msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
              }
              return msg;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
              //mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
         }
      }.execute(null, null, null);
  }
  ```

But when I try to send data to GCM from my locationService class my program crashes.

```
public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                HomeActivity t = new HomeActivity();
                t.sendMessageToGCMAppServer("Driving");
            }
        }
```

Anyone an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: `HomeActivity t = new HomeActivity()` <= yet another question about: *I don't know Activity Lifecycle, should I write apps for Android?* **NEVER create instance of Activity by yourself**

Comment: What is an other possibility to send data to that function?

Comment: the location listener is defined in some object, which prolly is the context itself(Service is context too, same as Activity, so you can use it instance to get gcm instance) ... you should fx make this method static and post the context if needed ... it is hard to explain if you have problems activity lifecycle and prolly with OOP basics ... **edit:** other quick fix: paste the sendMessageToGCMAppServer into service ... then try to fix the code(add necessery fields and stuff)

Comment: I already tried to change the function to static, but then I cant use the gcm functions anymore , like send etc. So that one I already tried.

Comment: you need to get gcm instance within the service itself